# Get Combobox Value when only one entry available

Tags: excel, combobox

I have a Combobox on a UserForm populated with multiple values.
Based on user input I keep redefining the Combobox to less and less entries in the DropDown.
At the point where there is only one value left in the Combo Dropdown, how do I get that value to appear in the Combobox Text field?

Comment: `Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex = 0`

Comment: I tried the .listIndex and it always keeps coming up at -1
To explain a little further....
When initially populated, the Combobox has 11 elements.
1st user choice filters it down to 8. The 2nd filters it down to 1 but now the user has to click the Combobox and select that one visible element.
That's the step I'm trying to skip.
If there's only one element, display that one in the Combobox without having to select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found my own solution.
The .listindex, after the fact, always comes up as -1 but each time I re-filter the combobox elements I can keep overwriting a variable within the AddItem loop with what the Combobox value is. When my count of elements = 1 then the value stored in that variable will be the last, and only, value that I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can access `ComboBox` values via the [`.List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.combobox.list) property.

```
expression.List(pvargIndex, pvargColumn)
```

keep in mind, the `pvargIndex` (row) and `pvargColumn` (column) do begin with the index `0`.
So to the access the first element, you would use `ComboBox.List(0, 0) = something`